# IPhone app use core-plot (What to fix)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

i'm making iphone app that use Core-Plot chart. The app have "SavolaViewController as a main class that include a button and when button clicked it's GoTo to another class named "ChartViewController" by this code

```
ChartViewControllerVar = [[ChartViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChartViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:ChartViewControllerVar animated:YES];
```

I have read about core-plot for 4-6 hours and i have not understand any of the tutorials(it's not understandable) [({"Please dont answer with tutorial link"})]

I have coped the Core-Plot code from the example in Core-Plot .zip file(you'll find the code in the link bellow).

and i have this msg in the console

> 2012-07-15 16:38:31.325 Savola[13105:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the
>   "ChartViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x140a022 0x19c2cd6 0x13b2a48 0x13b29b9 0x4102dd 0x410779 0x41099b 0x4199bc 0x414818 0x630565 0x417857
>   0x4179bc 0xca94792 0x4179fc 0x9a4f 0x3da5c5 0x3da7fa 0xc6f85d
>   0x13de936 0x13de3d7 0x1341790 0x1340d84 0x1340c9b 0x228f7d8 0x228f88a
>   0x349626 0x8c0a 0x2c55) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

What i want(If you can)

1. Fix the code to run in my app.
2. What does i need to but in the .xib file.
3. delete the codes unneeded.

[The code](http://ar2.co/Core.html)

Comment: I have not change any thing in the .xib file(it's include the UIView only) what should i put in the .xib file, and what i need to add in the .h(or/and).m file to make it connected with the code

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Core Plot. You have an IBOutlet in your .xib that's not connected properly.

Comment: Thanks, but i have not change any thing in the .xib file(it's include the UIView only) what should i put in the .xib file, and what i need to add in the .h(or/and).m file to make it connected.

Comment: Look at the example apps included with Core Plot.